# Demeaning independent variables

Tags: regression

I was reading a research paper in a reputable journal. They mention the following:
The balance sheet ratios are demeaned within quarter and normalized within quarter by dividing them by one standard deviation.

First of all, why would someone do that?
Second, if i want to replicate the output this standard deviation is what? standard deviation of the ratio across all companies in the sample for that quarter ? (cross sectional). Or time series of the ratio?

Answer (score 1):

You could call this "z-scoring within group."

1. People might want to do this if they want to remove mean differences (and standard deviation differences) between the quarters. While the means might have been 10, 20, 15, and 12 before, now all of the means are 0. If someone wants to eliminate the effect of quarter/time, then this is one way to do it.
2. The standard deviation you would divide by is the standard deviation for that quarter. So let's say the SD for each of the quarters are 1, 1.2, 0.8, and 1.1, then quarters one through four would be divided by each of those standard deviations, respectively.